# What does an icon's outline communicate to the user?

Tags: icons, material-design

I was looking through material design's icons, and I noticed they have four variations of the "add" icon. I don't know when I should select one variation over another.

What is the outline (or lack thereof) of an icon meant to communicate to the user?

[image: Material design's "add" icons]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used material design and have no experience in the same but I don't think look and feel of buttons have anything to do specifically with material design. So, in the specific example you have shared

1. first one looks like an icon where I would click to expand (or
   toggle the visibility) a section or an accordion
2. Second one looks like a button which would appear at the end of a grid header to add a column.
3. Third one looks like opposite of 'delete row' icon of iPhone. It looks ideal button for adding a child to a parent node of a hierarchy.
4. Fourth one is something I have never used and it looks more like a status indicator rather than an action element on which a click event is available.

Answer (score 0):

The shapes don't intrinsically signify anything, but when you have a set of icons together, you'll want them to have different shapes so users can more easily distinguish them from each other. [This brief article](http://uxmovement.com/buttons/why-distinct-icon-outlines-help-users-scan-faster/) talks about that. ([Here's a more in-depth article](http://boxesandarrows.com/optimizing-ui-icons-for-faster-recognition/) on other factors of icon design.)